# Query table button in BIG QUERY

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm currently following a step by step guide in the google data analytics course on how to use big query but I'm stuck and unable to proceed. Following the instructions, after clicking on 'view dataset', I'm supposed to click on 'query table' however this button cannot be found and I can only see 'create table' and even after clicking that, i'm completely lost. It seems the instructions have not been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer because it could help the next person. As of the time of this writing, if you only see the "create table" button and not the "query" button it is because the table that is in front of you has a subtable in it.

1- On the left side, under "Explorer," hit the drop-down arrow of the dataset you are working on. That dataset's name is found before the "period" in your Dataset ID (dataset_name.table_name).
2- Then, find your table and hit its drop-down arrow. Its name is found after the "period" in your Dataset ID (dataset_name.table_name).
3- Now, you will see one or more subtables. Pick the one you wish to query, click on it, and you will find the "query" button.

Long story short, as of September 4th, 2023, the syntax after the "FROM" operator in this exercise is "dataset_name.table_name.subtable_name".